# Get records from database while leaving out duplicates

Tags: mysql, database, recordset, no-duplicates

I have a table of zip codes in my MySQL database.  It uses PHPMyAdmin and I'm using PHP code.

The table looks something like this:

```
zip_codes(id, zip, state)
```

The problem here is that I want to generate a quick list of the states in this table.  However, I don't want a list of 33,000+ states that are 99.9% duplicates(many, many zip codes in each state).  I just want to show one Alabama for instance.  One Tennessee.

Is it possible to get a recordset like this?

Comment: Your question is way too vague - what DBMS are you using? What does your query look like?

Comment: use "group by state" at the end of query.eg  select state from zip_codes group by state

Comment: In that case the states must have been put in a different table and a "many to one" relationship should have been established between zip_codes table and states table! Things would have been way simpler!

Comment: It is MySQL, PHPMyAdmin and PHP.  Shafeeq answered my question below.  The reason there aren't two separate tables is because the zip code list I purchased had everything in one table.  It is also necessary for each zip code to have its state.

Comment: use distinct for the state column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `distinct`

```
SELECT DISTINCT state FROM zip_codes
```

Comment: Thank you.  That's easy to remember.  I appreciate it.  : )

Comment: GROUP BY in many cases is way more efficient than doing a SELECT DISTINCT. Of course, it depends on the data and the desired result. I would try profiling both ways just to be sure.